# How do I work in multiple fixes while waiting for a review in Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I've been looking around the web, and can't find the exact answer.

I've been using git under the [git flow model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for a couple of years now. I switched jobs recently, and here, we use Gerrit.

With Gerrit, among other restrictions, I don't seem to find the proper way to work on 2 separate fixes/features and review them at the same time. As I understand, I have to be working on top of the master branch, and can only push 1 commit at a time (unless I patch my initial review). Which is very different to what git is for me.

In git I could just do:

```
# work in a feature
git checkout -b feature/awesome
echo "nice" > nice.txt
git add nice.txt
git commit -m "My nice change"
git push -u origin feature/awesome

# work on a hotfix
git checkout -b hotfix/1.1.1
echo "fixed" > fixed.txt
git add fixed.txt
git commit -m "It's fixed"
git push -u origin hotfix/1.1.1
```

Then 2 guys would be reviewing my code before it would get merged into master or develop branches and properly tagged.

I know I just need to learn this new Gerrit model, but could someone help me figuring out how to work in 2 different reviews at once? I feel my productivity just got dropped to 20%.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm only a gerrit user, not an admin, so maybe I'm off-base here, but why can't you have several open changes in gerrit at the same time?  I have four open changes in the same project right at this moment.

I don't keep local branches.  In fact, there's rarely *anything* important in my working tree when I go home at night.

When I want to start a new change:

```
git reset --hard
git fetch
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master

# make my changes

git add ...
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/publish/master
```

When I want to work on some other change that's already in gerrit:

```
git reset --hard
git fetch ssh://mylogin@gerrit.my.employer.com/project refs/changes/nn/nnnnn/pp
git checkout FETCH_HEAD

# make my changes

git add ...
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/publish/master
```

Those `reset --hard` lines are seldom a problem because, like I said, I don't keep anything important in my local working tree.

The only trick is, if I've got two or more open changes that touch the same file, I may have to do a manual git merge to sort them out.  That's no worse than if I and some other developer tried to change the same file at the same time.

Comment: Ok, this is the mind shift I'm having... basically, I shouldn't keep changes locally to make this model work. Instead, all of the changes, even if they are not done, should be pushed into a review and then if there is anything new to add to it, I just keep checking out and submitting patches. This helps.

Comment: @mimoralea, This is the part where I don't know much about _administering_ gerrit but, at our site, a change is not "for review" until I invite someone to review it.  Also, I can push a change to refs/_drafts_/master, in which case it does not trigger continuous integration, and it can not be merged until I push a subsequent patch set in the normal way (i.e., to refs/publish/master).

Comment: What I do normally is `git diff > file.diff` before running `git reset --hard` and apply the selected patch when I need it later to work on a different gerrit review.

Comment: why do you have to reset --hard twice at the first change?

Comment: @dustin2022, I wrote that answer eight years ago, and then not long afterward, I moved on to a much smaller shop where  "code review" meant looking over someone's shoulder when they asked, "Hey! Can you take a look at this?" I honestly don't remember. Maybe it was just a voodoo magic/cargo cult thing.

Answer (score 1):

The simple rule is: **never work on top of a review-in-progress commit**. Instead, create a local branch for every task **from the merged** `master` (or whatever) branch.

IIRC, the default setting in Gerrit is to merge those commits automatically, and as an admin you can change it to rebase (or more strict fast-forward-only merge).

If this cannot be done by the server (e.g., on conflicts), you'll have to fetch the first approved commit and rebase/merge the second onto it. (This does not break the above rule, because the first commit is now **merged**.)

So for your example, change

```
git checkout -b hotfix/1.1.1
```

to

```
git checkout -b hotfix/1.1.1 HEAD~
```